# Test compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0),this version Java Runtimerecognizesclass file versions up to 52.0

Tags: java

There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org/testng/annotations/Test has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Kindly provide the solution.

Have tried changing the compiler level to 1.8,still facing same issue.
I'm using Java 8.

Comment: The easiest way is to update your java version. Java 8 is end-of-life since march 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the version of `org/testng/annotations/Test` you are using was compiled with Java 11.

You'll have to see if there is an older version that is compatible with Java 8.

Comment: Specifically, the OP needs TestNG 7.5 or earlier; see https://testng.org/doc/ and search for "Requirements".